# Convert list<Object> get(0) to class

Tags: java

I have a DBHandler that is of generic type. The problem I am facing is that I am unable to cast the object to a class. What confuses me is why I can't cast the single InstrumentOLS from get(0)?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.sg.info.InstrumentOLS

InstrumentOLS ols = (InstrumentOLS)listOLSvalues.get(0);
```

The query will return fine but it contains a list of Object.

```
List<InstrumentOLS> listOLSvalues = dbHandler.selectNativeListQuery("SELECT * FROM INSTRUMENTOLS");

public List<T> selectNativeListQuery(String sql) {
    validateEntityManager();

    Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
    List<T> listObj = query.getResultList();
    return listObj;
}
```

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.Object` means that the element is an array of objects, i.e. `Object[]`. Are you expecting one of the elements of that array to be a `InstrumentOLS`?

Comment: What's `Query` here? Is this Hibernate? What is `em`? I don't see anything which is telling the query that it's meant to convert the results into `InstrumentOLS` objects... and the `selectNativeListQuery` method doesn't even know the type of `T` due to type erasure. Chances are you're going to have to change your method to pass in `InstrumentOLS.class`, and then pass that on to `createNativeQuery`.

Comment: I believe the jist of why you need `List<Object[]>` is that you can't be certain at runtime what type you will actually get back.  In other words, how could the program be certain that an `InstrumentOLS` object will come back for each record?

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't think so. You certainly cannot downcast implicitly, but for sure explicitly, can't you?

Comment: @cricket_007 Of course you can cast `Object`: `Object obj = "Hello"; String str = (String) obj;` will work just fine.

Comment: @cricket_007` Object o  = 5;  int x  = (int) o;`

Comment: @AndyTurner that's true! No I expected it to be of type InstrumentOLS

Comment: Why is this list not a List<InstrumentOLS> listOLSvalues ? I would have expected an implicit cast here.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using JPA, with MySQL

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Jon I needed to update to send in the InstrumentOLS class. This makes the return type into InstrumentOLS instead of Object.

```
List<InstrumentOLS> listOLSvalues = dbHandler.selectNativeListQuery("SELECT * FROM SGWebNN.INSTRUMENTOLS", InstrumentOLS.class);
```

Then in the generic DBHandler

```
public List<T> selectNativeListQuery(String sql, Class aClass) {
        validateEntityManager();

        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, aClass);
        List<T> listObj = query.getResultList();
        return listObj;
    }
```